# Why Express res.render dumps the render output (EJS template) in console?

Tags: node.js, express

EJS compiles js to be executed, the js is then dumped in console somewhere along the way in res.render. How could I switch this logging off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something like this:

```
res.render('view', { debug : true, ... });
```

(or `debug` is part of the data that you're passing to the template)

This sets EJS's `debug` option, which dumps the generated function to stdout. The only way to fix this (AFAIK) is to rename `debug` to something else.

Comment: Spot on! I'm impressed to say the least - would never figure this out on my own. I indeed had "debug" as a parameter I was passing to the template.